# What is the state of C99 support in major compilers / toolchains?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c99, toolchain

A response to a comment I made here made me stop and think: "I don't really know what the state of C99 support is."

Wikipedia gives details for a few compilers, but I'm not familiar enough with C99 to know all the bits and pieces of the standard, so I'm looking for a gestalt overview answer to the question:

What is the state of C99 support in major compilers / toolchains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. MSVC: Intentionally not implemented unless it overlaps with C++
2. GCC: Most of the useful parts are in (and have been for awhile). Some missing features.
3. clang: Claims full C99 support

Comment: Also GCC documents the level of C99 support here: http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Comment: Finally, I don't know if it counts as a 'major' compiler, but it's often considered important due to its level of standards support: Comeau claims full C99 support: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/features.html#c99